# How to find the order of growth of a sum?

Tags: algorithm

I am wondering how to find the order of growth of: the sum from 0 to n-1 of `(i^2+1)^2`

First of all, I am assuming that I need to just find the closed-form of the summation (i.e. just as the sum from 1 to n of k is `(n(n+1))/2` ).

Assuming this is true, how do I tackle this problem? I have never worked to find the closed-form of a summation where the terms to be summed are of such a high order of magnitude (the 4th power).

Yes, this is a homework problem, but the teacher didn't explain it at all and it doesn't look like anyone has discussed a problem of this type on SO. Any help I can get would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to finish your homework, but provide you with some hints.

1. `(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab`
2. summation of `a^i` can be found from wikipedia page
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation